# Where did code first put my data?

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS; Database=WEBGENERIC; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I use this connection string, Entity Framework creates a database `WEBGENERIC` as expected.

If I remove the `Database=WEBGENERIC;` part of the string, the app still works and stores data but the database is nowhere to be found.

The default database for the login is `master` but it doesn't have any tables in it so I still don't know where the data has been stored.

So where is the data?

Comment: Have you looked in the `App_Data` folder?

Comment: If I were you I would trace the instance with SQL Server Profiler to see what it's outputting, but then again I'm a SQL guy and love that tool (even with it's faults)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud It wasn't there.

Comment: @David I thought of that but it wasn't installed.